# Issue with redis in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis

To store cache I use Redis. After using this command:

```
php artisan cache:clear --tags=tag
```

I see the error below:

> Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it issue related to this issue in [github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25547)

To fix it you can change Illuminate\Cache\Console\ClearCommand.php

from

```
if (! $successful) {
    return $this->error('Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.');
}
```

to

```
if ($successful === false) {
    return $this->error('Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.');
}
```